# How to check if part of key is in a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a piece of code that can check whether a part of a "word" is inside of a multi-dimensional array.

```
     foreach($teamMembers as $key => $value){
       if(preg_match('/^1.1./', $key)){
            $countCount += $key;
            $answerCount++;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to use this, but no luck.

I need to count all numbers when the `key`starts with '1.1.'
It's inside a multidimensional array. Maybe that's the reason why it's not working?

The places where I need to get the data from is always different. 
`$teamMembers[0]`
`$teamMembers[1]` etc.

Edit:

The `1.1.` does not contain any wildcards. An array looks like this:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [respondentNummer] => Respondent 2 
    [respondentNaam] =>  Dred Back 
    [respondentGroep] =>  Team members 
    [respondentScoRev] =>  SCORE
    [antwoord] => Array
        (
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The purpose of the team is well known] => 4
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The overriding objectives of the team are known] => 4
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The direction in which the team should work is clear] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The goals the team must reach are clearly stated.] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The members share their views of the goals of the team] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The results expected of the team are clear to the members] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, The team tackles problems in a way that is determined in advance] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, All members of the team agree on the way the work is conducted] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, Everyone in the team has the same opinion as to how the team should work] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, The team knows the extent of its authority] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, The team's sphere of responsibility is precisely delimited] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, It is clear to everyone what the team's authority of decision is] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, Members back up the decisions made, even if they do not fully agree] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, The team feels a common responsibility for the results gained] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, The team assumes a common accountability for bad results] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , The team utilises the strengths of the members] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , Team members supplement each other] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , The members all contribute their skills] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The team's efforts is beneficial to the rest of the organisation Everyone knows  the purpose of the team] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The overriding objectives of the team are known] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The team knows what its main tasks are] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, The team has insight into specialist areas] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, The team has knowledge of all important areas] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, All important functional areas are represented in the team] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, All mutual appointments are held] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, Everyone arrives to meetings in time] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, Team members are prepared for the meetings] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, The team usually agrees on decisions made] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, The team seeks to reach agreement on major decisions] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, Important decisions are made in consent] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team reacts to changes in the business environment] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team reconsiders issues when the conditions are changed] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team pays attention to changes that occur] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, Everybody respects the others' opinions] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, The members show consideration for the dissimilarity of the others] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, The members respect that opinions may differ] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team's efforts lead to tangible results] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team strives to show visible results] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team sets result objectives for all important functional areas] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team takes new initiatives in time] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team will continuously ensure that the organisation can lift its tasks] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team will allocate extra resources as needed] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The members of the team listen to the staff] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The team seeks information in the organization] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The team makes clear information available on its decisions] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team knows which issues to deal with] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team emphasises the implementing of decisions made] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team's decisions are implemented] => 4
            [4.5. Continual improvement, The team thinks about how to take decisions and how to improve them for the future] => 4
        )

    [weging] => Array
        (
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The purpose of the team is well known] => 4
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The overriding objectives of the team are known] => 4
            [1.1. Common Values and Purpose, The direction in which the team should work is clear] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The goals the team must reach are clearly stated.] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The members share their views of the goals of the team] => 4
            [1.2. Clear Goals, The results expected of the team are clear to the members] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, The team tackles problems in a way that is determined in advance] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, All members of the team agree on the way the work is conducted] => 4
            [1.3. Aligned Direction, Everyone in the team has the same opinion as to how the team should work] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, The team knows the extent of its authority] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, The team's sphere of responsibility is precisely delimited] => 4
            [1.4. Defined authority, It is clear to everyone what the team's authority of decision is] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, Members back up the decisions made, even if they do not fully agree] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, The team feels a common responsibility for the results gained] => 4
            [2.1. Commitment to team, The team assumes a common accountability for bad results] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , The team utilises the strengths of the members] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , Team members supplement each other] => 4
            [2.2. Effective composition , The members all contribute their skills] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The team's efforts is beneficial to the rest of the organisation Everyone knows  the purpose of the team] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The overriding objectives of the team are known] => 4
            [2.3. Team Role Behaviour, The team knows what its main tasks are] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, The team has insight into specialist areas] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, The team has knowledge of all important areas] => 4
            [2.4. Functional expertise, All important functional areas are represented in the team] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, All mutual appointments are held] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, Everyone arrives to meetings in time] => 4
            [3.1. Team rules followed, Team members are prepared for the meetings] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, The team usually agrees on decisions made] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, The team seeks to reach agreement on major decisions] => 4
            [3.2. Effective Decision making, Important decisions are made in consent] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team reacts to changes in the business environment] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team reconsiders issues when the conditions are changed] => 4
            [3.3. Flexible and responsive, The team pays attention to changes that occur] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, Everybody respects the others' opinions] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, The members show consideration for the dissimilarity of the others] => 4
            [3.4. Good relationships, The members respect that opinions may differ] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team's efforts lead to tangible results] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team strives to show visible results] => 4
            [4.1. Business and result focus, The team sets result objectives for all important functional areas] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team takes new initiatives in time] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team will continuously ensure that the organisation can lift its tasks] => 4
            [4.2. Improvement orientation, The team will allocate extra resources as needed] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The members of the team listen to the staff] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The team seeks information in the organization] => 4
            [4.3. Positive relations outside of team, The team makes clear information available on its decisions] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team knows which issues to deal with] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team emphasises the implementing of decisions made] => 4
            [4.4. Sets business direction, The team's decisions are implemented] => 4
            [4.5. Continual improvement, The team thinks about how to take decisions and how to improve them for the future] => 4
        )

)
```

EDIT:

The next lines of code almost completely works.

```
$count=0;
foreach($teamMembers[0] as $item){
  if(is_array($item)){
    foreach($item as $k=>$v){
        if(strpos($k,'1.1')===0){
            $count += $v;
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

But I need `$teamMembers[0]` to go into the direction of $`teamMembers[0]['antwoord']. Else it'll pick up wrong data. Does anyone know how I can get this implemented? Just putting '['antwoord']` behind it gives all `0` as output.

Comment: Do you mean to use `.` as a wildcard?  I don't think you need regex.  What does your input look like?  What is your expected output for your sample input?  Please complete your question.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php to iterate by all elemnts of multidimesional array

Comment: @mickmackusa I've added some more info.

Comment: Do not post data or code as images.  Give us usable text please.  Do you have more data in that array?  This will determine if a single key can be used to get the subarray values, or if `array_column()` is necessary, or finally `array_walk_recursive()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa My bad! But I can't post the array, I think. It's imported from an .CSV file.I'll paste the first bit of the array. The pasted bit repeats itself with new data. So if you've seen one you've seen them all.

Comment: You don't have a `$teamMembers[0]` element based on what you've posted as sample data.  Do you have more 1st-level arrays?  I mean is there also `Respondent 1` and `Respondent 3` etc that have their own set of data?

Comment: How do YOU know which subarray you are going to access?  Are you going to access them all?  Are you going to search by `naam`?  Do you want a truly dynamic method? Something like this: https://3v4l.org/ph6vC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate each subarray and call `array_filter()` with `strpos()` then add that count to your total tally.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/G5KEe))

```
$count=0;
foreach($teamMembers as $item){
    if(is_array($item)){
        $count+=sizeof(array_filter($item,function($k){return strpos($k,'1.1.')===0;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Output:

```
6
```

---

This is the same type of method with loops:

```
$count=0;
foreach($teamMembers as $item){
    if(is_array($item)){
        foreach($item as $k=>$v){
            if(strpos($k,'1.1.')===0){
                ++$count;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $count;
```

---

---

Furthermore...

If you want to target a specific subarray and count how many of those associative elements have a key that starts with a certain substring you can use:

```
function count_keys_beginning_with($array,$substring){
    return sizeof(array_filter($array,function($k)use($substring){return strpos($k,$substring)===0;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
}
echo count_keys_beginning_with($teamMembers['antwoord'],'1.1.');
// output: 3
```

Or without a custom function call:

```
$answer_count=sizeof(array_filter($teamMembers['antwoord'],function($k){return strpos($k,'1.1.')===0;},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
echo $answer_count;
// output: 3
```

Comment: @Carlove Now that I know the structure of your data, I have posted a non-recursive method.  You are expecting `6` as the output, correct?

Comment: I was expecting 12. 4+4+4. Thanks for your help so far! For some reason the code that works in the demo doesn't work for me. So there might be some other strange thing going on. ( Even though we're using the same array).

Comment: @Carlove Tell me why you expect 12?  There are 12 `1.` keys in each subarray.  If you search for `1.` you should get 24 from your sample array.

Comment: Ahh, found the issue. It still needed a `[x]` `$teamMembers[0]'

But, it needs to count the value of the `1.1.` not count the amount of occurrences.

Comment: Also.. I completely forgot. It may only count the `['antwoord']` occurrences.

Comment: Your `foreach` works out! but sadly it doesnt if you specify which way of the array it has to go ex: `teamMembers[0]['antwoord']`

Comment: So are you saying your expected output is `3`?  You should update your question.

Comment: @Carlove Do you need to store the count for each subarray?  `answers=3`, `weights=3`, etc?

Comment: I needed to store the value of the key, not the amount of occurrences. But it worked out now that I turned the multidimensional array into two separate ones. One more `question answers` and one for `question relevance`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`array_walk_recursive` + `strpos` solution:

```
$teamMembers = [
    'responderScoRev' => 'Score',
    'antwoord' => ['1.2. text' => 1, '1.1.2 text' => 1, '1.1.3 text' => 1],
    '1.1.3' => 3
    ];

$cnt = 0;
array_walk_recursive($teamMembers, function($v, $k) use(&$cnt){
   if (strpos($k, '1.1.') === 0) $cnt++; 
});

print_r($cnt);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! But it has to count the value of `$k`. Doing `$cnt += $k` doesn't work., for some reason.

Comment: @Carlove, do you expect the result to be a float number or in some other format?